# stack files of various folders using R

Tags: r, stack, landsat

I stacked certain tif files of a Landsat image, as is shown:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Landsat/L5__002072-09MAY-2006")
may2006<-list.files(".",pattern="*B[123457]\\.tif$", ignore.case=TRUE) 

[1] "LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B1.TIF" 
[2] "LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B2.TIF" 
[3] "LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B3.TIF"
[4] "LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B4.TIF"
[5] "LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B5.TIF"
[7] "LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B7.TIF"

landsat_stack <- stack(may2006)
```

I want to do the same, but for all the images of the folder Landsat (each folder  been a separate stack )

```
setwd("C:/Users/Landsat")
foldersList <- normalizePath(list.dirs(full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)) 

[1] "C:\\Users\\Landsat\\L5__002072-09MAY-2006"
[2] "C:\\Users\\Landsat\\L5_001073_02MAY-2006" 
[3] "C:\\Users\\Landsat\\L5_001073_14MAY-1987" 
[4] "C:\\Users\\Landsat\\L8__002072-7MAY-2017"
```

Is it possible to do this simultaneously for all the images?
I thought in first do one list with all tif files(no matter the folder), and then with a loop stacks only the files that have a match in the name (condition 1), but finish with this pattern "B[123457]"(condition 2)

```
all_Landsat<-list.files(".",pattern="*B[123457]\\.tif$", ignore.case=TRUE, recursive= TRUE)
all_Landsat
[1] "L5__002072-09MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B1.TIF" 
[2] "L5__002072-09MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B2.TIF"
[3] "L5__002072-09MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B3.TIF" 
[4] "L5__002072-09MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B4.TIF"
[5] "L5__002072-09MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B5.TIF" 
[6] "L5__002072-09MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B7.TIF"
[7] "L5_001073_02MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_001073_20060502_20161122_01_T1_B1.TIF"  
[8] "L5_001073_02MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_001073_20060502_20161122_01_T1_B2.TIF" 
[9] "L5_001073_02MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_001073_20060502_20161122_01_T1_B3.TIF"  
[10]"L5_001073_02MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_001073_20060502_20161122_01_T1_B4.TIF" 
[11]"L5_001073_02MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_001073_20060502_20161122_01_T1_B5.TIF"  
[12]"L5_001073_02MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_001073_20060502_20161122_01_T1_B7.TIF" 
[13]"L5_001073_14MAY-1987/LM50010731987134AAA03_B1.TIF"                     
[14]"L5_001073_14MAY-1987/LM50010731987134AAA03_B2.TIF"                    
[15]"L5_001073_14MAY-1987/LM50010731987134AAA03_B3.TIF"                     
[16]"L5_001073_14MAY-1987/LM50010731987134AAA03_B4.TIF"                    
[17]"L8__002072-7MAY-2017/LC08_L1TP_002072_20170507_20170515_01_T1_B1.TIF"  
[18]"L8__002072-7MAY-2017/LC08_L1TP_002072_20170507_20170515_01_T1_B2.TIF" 
[19]"L8__002072-7MAY-2017/LC08_L1TP_002072_20170507_20170515_01_T1_B3.TIF"  
[20]"L8__002072-7MAY-2017/LC08_L1TP_002072_20170507_20170515_01_T1_B4.TIF" 
[21]"L8__002072-7MAY-2017/LC08_L1TP_002072_20170507_20170515_01_T1_B5.TIF"  
[22]"L8__002072-7MAY-2017/LC08_L1TP_002072_20170507_20170515_01_T1_B7.TIF"
```

But I can´t find the right code for the 2 conditions:

```
for (i in all_Landsat){
    if (grep(pattern="+B[123457]\\.tif$", ignore.case=FALSE)){
    stack(i) 
  }
}
```

Comment: do you mean you want each folder to be a separate stack or you want all the tifs in one stack?

Comment: `all_Landsat<-list.files("C:/Users/Landsat",pattern="*B[123457]\\.tif$", ignore.case=TRUE, recursive= TRUE)`

Comment: Yes, what I want is to make a separate stack for each folder . Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked this but hope this works:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Landsat")    
a<-list.dirs(getwd(),recursive = FALSE )
flist <- list()
stackfile <- list()
for (i in 1:length(a)){  
    flist[[i]] <-  list.files(a[i], recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern = "tif$")  

    stackfile[[i]] <- stack(flist[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Thank you ANUP, but I´m trying to make a separate stack for each folder

Comment: how many folders are there in total ? if it is only  3 or 4 you could re use the same read file and stack code. @Cotimaass

Comment: In total I have a lot of folders (25 at least)

Comment: @Cotimaass I've updated my answer. Does that work ? I couldnot check this because I don't have your setup.

Comment: Thanks @anup I got an error when I run the loop:                            Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

In addition: Warning message:
In flist[i] <- list.files(a, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.

Comment: thats because I made a mistake .  i've updated the answer. @Cotimaass

Comment: Thanks. Now I got this error: Error in stack.default(flist[[i]]) : 
  at least one vector element is required

Comment: @Cotimaass that should be a vector. I did not get such an error. Are you sure you copied the code as it is ? Do this: Run the code by commenting the `stackfile[[i]] <- stack(flist([[i]])` and check `str(flist)` : should return `List of 25` `$:chr [1:6] "C:/Users/Landsat/......."`

Comment: @Cotimaass comment out the last line of the code by putting a `#` sign infront of the code so that the code doesnot try to stack the files. and then hopefully there won't be any errors produced. then check `str(flist)`. Is it a vector or not ?

Comment: I got this:
List of 4
 $ : chr(0) 
 $ : chr(0) 
 $ : chr(0) 
 $ : chr(0)

Comment: then @Cotimaass obviously there's a problem in `list.files()`, may be pattern is wrong. try using `pattern = "TIF$"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @anup. I finally solved the problem with this code. It returns a list of the TIF images stacked by folder.

```
setwd("C:/Users/Landsat")    
a<-list.dirs(getwd(),recursive = FALSE )

landsat<- apply(a,function (dir){  
    img<-stack(list.files(path=dir,ignore.case= TRUE, 
    pattern="*B[123457]\\.tif$", full.names= TRUE))
})
```